# Display one object - after clicking another object in JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a very amateur question since I am very new to coding!

I have 4 button inputs "skolefag", ""sport", "fritid", "diverse" and 4 large squares (stacked upon eachother, different colors, but you can only see the red one)

I want to switch between divs (the large squares) when i click on the different categories, so that the contents and background color of the correct/matching large square shows.

What would be the easiest technique to achieve this trough?

[image]
Sorry again and thank you in advance!

Comment: Any code you find out there related to javascript tabs - could work (Google it). Start here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp. Vertical tabs (Same layout like you Q screenshot): https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution (which I think is neat):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  change_menu("home");
});

function change_menu(
  menu_to_show
) {
  ['home', 'second', 'third'].forEach(function(memuee) {
    document.getElementById(memuee).style.display = 'none';
  });
  document.getElementById(menu_to_show).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div style='display: flex;font-size: 200%;'>

  <div>
    <div style="background:green" onclick="change_menu('home')">Home</div>
    <div style="background:red" onclick="change_menu('second')">Go To Second</div>
    <div style="background:blue" onclick="change_menu('third')">Go To Third</div>
  </div>

  <div id="home" style="background:green">
    HOME PAGE
  </div>
  <div id="second" style="background:red">
    SECOND PAGE
  </div>
  <div id="third" style="background:blue">
    THIRD PAGE
  </div>

</div>
```

Of course this could be further optimized by referencing "page" `div`s by the "button" `div`'s ids (e.g. `home_page` from `home_button`) or grouping `id`s within given "wrapper" `div`s, [using `class`es](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp), etc., but I think this is the essential solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use onclick attribute on you button or add a click eventListenner to it.
Then you create a function that is called by onclick="myfunction(idButton)" or by your eventListener :

```
function myfunction(idButton) {
  document.getElementById("my-elmt-to-set-up").backgroundColor = docuement.getElementById(idbutton).backgroundColor
}
```

and same thing for color properties, review javascript lesson I think --> after lesson you can make some incredible interactions

Comment: this does not include content changing, which i presume is quite essential